# How to change the existing user role in Kaizala

Tags: kaizala

I have added a user as an Admin to the group and later on I wanted to make him as only a member of the group. I was not able to do it because I do not see any option to change the user role once the user was added to the group.

Alternative: Only way I could do is, I have to remove the user from the group and add it as member/admin again while adding. This is will be tedious maintenance activity if you work with large user base.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from your Kaizala app. Currently Kaizala Management portal doesn't allow edit of user role directly.